# Cordova platform add: Failed to run 'java -version'

Tags: windows, cordova, ant

I have the next problem:

When I run, the fist time, `cordova platform add android` originate the follow error

```
Error: ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and added to your path.
```

**I have ant installed and added in my path**

The second time that I run `cordova platform add android`, it says:

```
Error: Failed to run 'java -version', make sure your java environment is set up
including JDK and JRE.
Your JAVA_HOME variable is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67
Error: Command failed: Access denied.
```

**I have my %JAVA_HOME% added**

I am using Windows 8.

**Any suggestions??**

---

*More information...*

```
`C:\temp\siete>cordova platform add android
Creating android project...

C:\Users\user\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and added to your path.
    at C:\Users\user\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\lib\check_reqs.js:47:27
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:652:7)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
Error: C:\Users\user\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\create.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)`
```

```
`C:\temp\siete>cordova platform add android
Creating android project...

C:\Users\user\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: Failed to run 'java -version', make sure your java environment is set upincluding JDK and JRE.
Your JAVA_HOME variable is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67
Error: Command failed: Acceso denegado.

    at C:\Users\user\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\lib\check_reqs.js:62:22
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:652:7)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
Error: C:\Users\user\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\create.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)`
```

Comment: try to run the commands from Administrator? what does Acceso denegado stand for? Have you installed ANT, Have U set environment variables such as ANT_HOME, ANDROID_HOME, JAVA_HOME, ANDROID_SDK?

Comment: "Acceso denegado"="Access denied"
I tried run from Administrator...
I have my environment variables setted... and changed, and re-setted...

Comment: There should be a folder **.cordova** in `"C:\Users\user\"` directory. Delete the **.cordova** folder. Then delete the **project** directory, Install the cordova again and run **all** the cordova commands again.

Comment: Either... :(
I'm thinking to restore all the system... And reinstall all again

Comment: first you can try my suggestion, if it does not work then you can reinstall all again.

Comment: I tried. Thanks for the recommendation... I also tried reinstalling all, but I still have the same problem. I still did not restore the system..

Comment: Maybe you need JDK 1.6 Java 32 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need JDK 1.6
Java 32 bits.
Do you speak spanish? - Take a look at this link:

http://www.phonegapspain.com/tutorial/como-instalar-phonegap-en-windows-7-paso-a-paso/

Gretings!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add %JAVA_HOME%\bin to the PATH variable.

The command shell can only see what's in the %PATH% directory.